# Getting reminders on the home screen not the notification center

Tags: macos, reminders

I want to create reminders in the Reminders app and have them create pop-ups on my main screen, not in the notification center because if they are time-sensitive I might not see them right away.

Is there a way to harness reminder notifications to display prominently on the Mac display and not just Notification Center?

Comment: When you say Home Screen and tag this with Mac, I'm assuming you want these on the Mac desktop? Please edit further if the OS / situation isn't correct.

Comment: Yes, mac desktop thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, I can suggest that you have set the notification appearance parameter to **none**, which means that the notifications won't appear on your screen.

You can set the notifications to appear as **banners** (notifications appear on the screen and disappear after a while) or **alerts** (notifications stay on the screen until you dismiss them). To set those parameters, go to **System Settings** > **Notifications** > **Reminders** and select a notification style.

You can also turn on "**Show notifications on lock screen**" to have them show directly when you open you Mac (when closed).

[image]

---

Also, when I re-read the title, you say "not the Notification Center". You can still disable "Show in Notification Center" if you want.

Comment: Hi there, I don't seem to have "none" selected, it looks like "Alerts" are selected but still I don't get pop ups. Any idea why?

Comment: @ak0000 The problem could also come from notification grouping; what have you set for it?

Comment: Notification grouping: automatic @thinkr

Comment: @ak0000 Try setting it to "Off" and see what happens. There could be a "bug" where the notifications come only in Notifications Center but *grouped*

Comment: No luck it seems, the pop-up is invisible even with that setting set to off